# Facebook Login in Android application

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, sdk, for-loop

I need to create an Android application where user will provide the userid and password of the facebook then he will login inside the application.
For this I want to use my own LoginPage.I want to create Loginpage using android layout standard.
I am not able to achieve it in my own way.
Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: You CANT ask for users logins and passwords of any kind. Instead, you have to send the user for the facebook authentication page, and access user information using a access token.

Comment: This is my problem.I dont want to use facebook authentication page.Any work-around?

Comment: I have the same question. Dileep did you find any solution?

Comment: Good Demo Here :- http://www.demoadda.com/demo/android/login-with-facebook_108

Answer (score 2):

This is a good start : http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/android/ and http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/androidsdk/authentication/

Comment: I dont want to use facebook authentication page.Without facebook authentication page , i want to create my own login page.

Comment: Facebook like twitter use Oauth authentification now, and the all point of Oauth is to NOT give your login or password to anyone else. I don't think they authorize classic authentification anymore but i maybe wrong. [link](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/)

Comment: Even I think that we cant ask for userid and password from the user.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own login page using the login activity template provided in the Android SDK. See [*this link*](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/templates.html#login-activity) to there website for more information. I used this template myself for an application I am developing and found it very helpful.

However, as far as I understand, if you want Facebook Integration you need to use the proper authentication page. To do this you need to download the Facebook APK. The Facebook developers page details the steps to implement such a login process in Step 6 of their  [*Getting Started with the Facebook SDK for Android site*](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/)